# GUI binding for pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyglet, pyopengl

I have three questions:

1. Is there any 'normal' way to do `GUI` in `pyglet` (not drawing
   buttons with hands)?
2. If no, is there any way to use `PyOpenGL`
   bindings (`Togl`, `glglue`) with `pyglet`?
3. If no again, is there any
   way to give to these bindings `pyglet` context instead of `PyOpenGL`'s
   (i think, there is possible in some way, cause they both are just
   wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tkinter](http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/). It's a build in library for python.